# jquery before() function

Tags: jquery

I have a form something like this:

```
<form>
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        <li><input type="submit" value="go" /></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

And then a jquery expression like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addField').click(function() {
        var cloned = $('#someid').clone(true);
        $('ul:last-child').before(cloned); // <-- this doesn't work
    });
});
```

And jquery inserts the cloned object before the UL, not before the last child of the UL, as intended. If I change the jquery expression to "form ul:last-child" then it inserts before the form. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the meaning of the `// <-- this doesn't work` comment? From the text of your question, it sure sounds like that LoC works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ul:last-child` matches a `<ul>` which is the last child of its parent.

You want `ul li:last-child`, which matches an `<li>` which is the last child of its parent and which is in a `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0):

specifying `ul:last-child` select the ul that is the last child of its parent. what you are looking for is `ul :last-child`. This will select the last child of the ul.